# Isset function notice in php

Tags: php, isset

The code below throws a notice.

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: product_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\WilliesFishing\admin\product\index.php on line 55

I checked and I am on `line 55` but it doesn't like the `isset()`.

I have also tried `if(isset($_GET['product_id'];` and it throws the same error.  Shouldn't this work?

```
case 'show_add_edit_form':
    if (isset($product_id)) {
        $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
    } else {  
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id']; // --> Line #55
    }
```

Comment: please provide the exact line that is throwing the Notice.

Comment: I corrected the code above with the line that is causing it

Comment: if we don't init a valible before isset(),if you use isset($product_id) ,it should be notice you to init valible before use try @isset($product_id)

Comment: @LiuqingHu suggesting that somebody should introduce error suppression into their code is terrible advice.

Comment: @vascowhite use error suppression is a simple and crude way.@user3562189 http://stackoverflow.com/a/23378104/1969039 will be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `$_GET` or `$_POST` doesn't have an index named `product_id`. Your `isset` line only checks whether the global variable `$product_id` is set, which may not imply anything about the state of `$_GET` and/or `$_POST`. You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
if (isset($_GET['product_id')) {
    $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
} else if (isset($_POST['product_id')) {
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
} else {
    // provide a reasonable default, or otherwise handle the edge-case, in here
}
```

Comment: Its still throwing that same notice for some reason

Comment: Try again - there was a missing _ in my second `$_POST`, I had accidentally typed `$POST` (so the thing you checked in the `else if` wasn't the same thing you read from).

Comment: Awesome I should have caught that.  I guess I just dont get why the isset wasnt working in this case

Comment: Because you weren't checking whether `$_POST['product_id']` was set before trying to read from it. The only thing YOUR code checked was `$product_id`, so when you went to read `$_POST['product_id']`, you were reading from an index that didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use isset on your get parameters. Something like this:

```
 if (isset($_GET['product_id'])) {
     $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
 }
 else if (isset($_POST['product_id'])) {  
     $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
 }
```

The error tells you this because $_GET['product_id'] has no value. So instead of using $product_id. use the request parameter in the condition instead